# sublime text "The package specified, HTML5-master, is not available"

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I did a manual install of HTML5-master accidentally (forgot that i had already installed it via package control) so I manually deleted it only to now get this prompt everytime i open sublime text.  is there any way to delete this text?

i'm on sublime text 2 via mac mavericks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `Package Control.sublime-settings` installed list for that package. Guessing the it got added there at some point.